# GraphQLError Unknown type "XYZMutationInput"

Tags: graphql, graphene-python, graphene-django, graphql-python

**How to create graphql input type for DRF serializer?**

I am using django rest framework (DRF) serializers, `graphene-django`, and I am able to see the `CreateThingMutationInput` type defined in `graphiql`:

```
  mutation TestCreate($input: CreateThingMutationInput!) {
    createProjectThing(input: $input) {
      id
      errors {
        field
        messages
      }
    }
  }
```

However, I am unable to run:

```
        schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query)
        result = schema.execute(self.query, variables=variables)
```

I get:

```
[GraphQLError('Unknown type "CreateThingMutationInput".',)]
```

With the following:

```
class CreateThingMutation(SerializerMutation):
    class Meta:
        serializer_class = ThingListViewSerializer


class Mutation(graphene.ObjectType):
    debug = graphene.Field(DjangoDebug, name="_debug")

    create_project_thing = CreateThingMutation.Field()
```

I've also tried:

```
class CreateThingMutationInput(graphene.ObjectType):
    input = graphene.Field(convert_serializer_to_input_type(ThingListViewSerializer))
```

As well as trying to define a:

```
class Input:
    input = graphene.Field(convert_serializer_to_input_type(ThingListViewSerializer))
```

I can also see the type defined from `graphql-codegen` in `types.d.ts`:

```
export type CreateThingMutationInput = {
  id?: Maybe<Scalars['Int']>,
  ...
}
```

related:

- https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene/issues/531
- https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene-django/blob/master/docs/mutations.rst#django-rest-framework
- https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene-django/issues/121

Answer (score 2):

I forgot to add the `mutation` kwarg to:

```
schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query)
```

Should be:

```
schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query, mutation=Mutation)
```

Another reason this can happen for `GraphQLError('Unknown type "Number".',)` is if a query function gets an unexpected argument, for example calling `getThing` with a `Number`, instead of an `ID`:

```
query TestQueryWontWork(id: Number="") {
   getThing(id: $id)
}

query TestQueryWorks(id: ID!) {
   getThing(id: $id)
}
```